# Using Node.js to send and receive messages to/from SonicMQ (progress)

Tags: node.js, sonicmq

Does anyone know if it's possible, or have an example of using Node.js to connect to a SonicMQ broker? I have not been able to find any information or examples online.

Comment: Sort of related: [Receiving OpenMQ messages in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509805/receiving-openmq-messages-in-delphi). They mention that there's a C API, which you could integrate using [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use either a Sonic Connect exposing a rest service(need ESB) or defining an http Acceptor to communicate with the queue(Direct connection to broker).

Regards